# Have anyone worked with SCPI commands communicating with Function Generator in Raspbian OS using Python language?

Tags: raspbian

As I am new to work with SCPI commands, can anyone tell me how to write SCPI commands and how it can be configured with Function Generator in Raspbian OS using Python.

Comment: Raspbian is a Linux system.  If you look for Linux solutions they will work on the Pi as well.

Comment: which fun gen pls?